# Constructor Injection vs IocFactory

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

Today at work a collegue and I had a discussion about the following:

Basically we have a rule engine which works in the following way:

**RuleExecutor**

- Gets all rules to execute in the constructor like `public RuleExecutor(ICollection<IRule> rulesToExecute) { ... }`
- Executes all rules by calling `rule.ApplyRule();` for each rulesToExecute

**Rules**

- Provide method ApplyRule(); which executes the rule

Now we want the RuleExecutor to be executed in a cron job.

We had a discussion about how to retrieve an instance of the RuleExecutor.

I think the "correct way" is via constructor injection

```
public RuleCronJob(IRuleExecutor ruleExecutor) { ... }
```

My collegue wants to use a "IocFactory" which has a static method GetInstance<>.
So in the "execute method" of the cron job he would do something like `var ruleExecutor = IocFactory.GetInstance<IRuleExecutor>();`

```
public static TType GetInstance<TType>(params Tuple<string, object>[] constructorParameters)
    {
        if (constructorParameters.Any())
        {
            var constructorArgs = new Collection<ConstructorArgument>();
            foreach (var parameter in constructorParameters)
            {
                constructorArgs.Add(new ConstructorArgument(parameter.Item1, parameter.Item2, true));
            }

            return Kernel.Value.Get<TType>(constructorArgs.Cast<IParameter>().ToArray());
        }

        return Kernel.Value.Get<TType>();
    }
```

Kernel is a StandardKernel of Ninject.

I think the constructor injection is better because it allows for easier tests (mocking), IocFactory is actually a "ServiceLocator" which I think is an anti pattern and the IocFactory adds another dependency to the cronjob which isn't necessary... but I couln't convince him to use it because he thinks that the IocFactory "works as well so why not use it"...

- What would be some arguments to convince him to use constructor injection rather than the IocFactory?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://bash.org/?338364) is how you can answer his "works well" (and non-technical) argument.

If anything, his approach with `params Tuple<string, object>` is horrendous at best: maintenance nightmare, zero support from refactoring tools. Service Locator is effectively Singleton in disguise.

Using proper IoC you can leveage whatever advanced functionality your container of choice provides: different lifetimes, constructor and property injection, support for `Func<>` and `Lazy<>`, etc. With Service Locator, you get none of that.